# eclipse wont let me create a dynamic web project

Tags: java, eclipse, war

I recently downloaded java7 and eclipse indigo to my computer.  I am trying to create a dynamic web project but it wont let me.  It will only let me create General, CVS, Java, and Maven projects.

I would like to compile a project into a WAR file and am having difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have downloaded the Eclipse Classic or the Eclipse for Java Developers package, you will need an additional component called **Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools**. I suggest you install the whole Web,XML, Java EE and OSGI Enterprise Development section.

If you download Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers you won't need to add it.

Use this [guide](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-129.htm) to install new components in your IDE.